# Use VBA to close a shell window and append a datestamp to filename

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I have a shell command that uses curl to capture live audio output from a port on our call server.

What I would like to know is; 1) how can I stop the recording (close the shell window) using VBA and, 2) how can I append a date/time stamp to the file?

Currently, when I run the macro, it opens a shell window and executes the command just fine. The file continues recording until I close the shell window. I would like to give the user a button that will close the shell window for them and timestamp the recording. ex. "voice_2019-05-20 1019.wav"

Any help greatly appreciated!

PS I realize the shell command can be executed without using cmd - so there is no shell window - but I've had even less luck with that. At least with the shell window I can close it and stop the recording. When I run it without cmd, it just records forever until I kill the process. Happy to try any/all suggestions!

```
Sub RecordAudio()
    Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /K" & "curl 92.68.0.10:8888 > i:\voicetemp\voice.wav", vbMinimizedFocus) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to close a task process:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CloseTask()

    Dim oServ As Object
    Dim cProc As Variant
    Dim oProc As Object

    Set oServ = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

    For Each oProc In cProc
        If oProc.Name Like "WhateverYouNeed" Then
          oProc.Terminate
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Also, for the timestamp: `Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")` could do. You can use that on a cell wherever you need.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Your solution works nicely to kill processes I know the names of but I don't know how to identify and close the process task name created when I run : Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /K" & "curl 92.68.0.10:8888 > i:\voicetemp\voice.wav"